# Javascript form validation failing

Tags: javascript, html, validation

i am trying to validate a form with java script .. yet the javascript does not output anything and the form completes into processing.

here is the script tag:

here is the form tag:

```
<FORM  id="frm" name="newCustomer" METHOD="POST" ACTION="register.php" onsubmit="return      validateNewCustomer()">
```

i've created this label so that java script can write the warnings:

```
  <TH WIDTH="30%" NOWRAP> <Label>First Name</Label></TH>
      <TD WIDTH="70%"><INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="f_name" 
                             SIZE="8" MAXLENGTH="8">
         <label class ="err" id="errname"></label>
```

Here is the valdiation function :

```
  function validateNewCustomer(){

var name = document.getElementById('f_name').value;
var okCustomer = true;

if(name == ""){
document.getElementById('errname').innerHTML = "Error Name";
okCustomer = okCustomer && false;
}

return okCustomer;

}
```

I should note that i tried to make the function return false , but it still didn't stop php processing.

I appreciate your help.

Thank you.

Comment: Any error messages? Can you give a live example?

Comment: give the input an id? id="f_name"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is wrong use

`var name = document.getElementsByName('f_name').value;`

instead of

`var name = document.getElementsById('f_name')[0].value;`

Comment: i gave all inputs IDs , and tried both Byname , and ByiD , I have a feeling that the php continues processing after javascript is done.

Comment: it is document.getElementsByName('f_name') not document.getElementByName('f_name'). there is 'Elements' not 'Element' please try. It is working on my system.

Comment: sorry it is document.getElementsByName('f_name')[0].value; This will work

Answer (score 1):

```
var name = document.getElementByName('f_name').value;
```

and

`okCustomer = false;` instead of `okCustomer = okCustomer && false;`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
if(name.value == ""){
```

instead of

```
if(name == ""){
```